# Problemas al actualizar de FontAwesome 4 a FontAwesome 5 en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, font-awesome, icons

Estoy trabajando en un sitio web hecho asp.net de mi trabajo.
Como es la primera vez que agarro este proyecto, estoy tratando de familiarizarme con todo su contenido.

Lo que veo es que la `MasterPage` está usando la versión 4.2.0 de `FontAwesome` para poner varios de los iconos que usa el sitio web como diseño.
En los programas que yo estoy creando quiero usar la versión 5.13.0 pero al testear los programas no me muestra correctamente los iconos e incluso me deja de mostrar muchos de la `MasterPage`

[image: Ejemplo1]

Lo que marco en rojo, en la `MasterPage` tiene un icono de edificio (fa-building en `FontAwesome`).
Lo que marco en verde, tiene dos imágenes de calendarios (fa-calendar-alt en `FontAwesome`).
Lo que marco en azul, son botones con los iconos de Impresora, Excel, csv y PDF (fa-print, fa-file-excel, fa-file-alt y fa-file-pdf en `FontAwesome`).

No tengo ni idea de por qué motivo no me reconoce los iconos si ya borré todas las referencias de `FontAwesome 4.2.0` y las cambié por las de `FontAwesome 5.13.0`.

La única diferencia en el cambio que hice yo es que las referencias a `FontAwesome 4.2.0` son a través de links a la web:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Yo lo que hice fue descargarme el kit de `FontAwesome 5.13.0`, guardarlo en el proyecto y hacer la referencia desde el proyecto:

```
<link href="Scripts/FontAwesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Hay varios iconos que cambiaron de nombres y otros que dejaron de existir en la nueva version, tienes que revisarlos uno a uno. La única solución.

Comment: Sí, los que yo uso se llaman de otra forma y ya lo corregí. Los de la MasterPage usé otros diferentes que eran mejores y los de esta ventana los estoy usando en otros proyectos sin problemas

Comment: `href="~/Scripts` ¿Has intentado con este símbolo al inicio ~ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me había faltado la referencia de los iconos en la ventana que estoy haciendo yo.

Agregando esto luego de la referencia de `FontAwesome` no tuve más problemas:

```
<link type="text/css" href="../Scripts/FontAwesome/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="../Scripts/FontAwesome/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Gracias a todos los que se tomaron el tiempo para comentar o responder la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Basta con que hagas la referencia a otro CDN que si tenga esa version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" />
```

Y como indican en los comentarios, asegurate de que los nombres sean los mismos ya que cambiaron los nombres de las clases con la nueva versión:

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/home

https://fontawesome.com/icons/home

Comment: Sí, el problema era que me faltaron referenciar las carpetas donde se encontraban los diseños de los iconos. Ahora tengo otro problema pero será cuestion de seguir investigando o a lo sumo será otro post. Gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada saludos compañero.

Para usar la paquetería de iconos FontAwesome.

1. Tener el estilo **.css** de los iconos.
2. De formar local todas sus dependencias en formato **.eot .svg .woff .ttf**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los puntos rojos marcados tengo mis archivos necesarios para referenciar al paquete de iconos.

1. **all.min.ccs** -> *Mi  hoja de estilos que ya estoy referenciando desde mi master page como:* [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. [Carpeta **WebFonts**] *La exportas a tu proyecto, la encuentras en: **fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web\webfonts** *

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora solo basta con referenciar al icono con una clase:
Ejemplo:

```
<div class="sidebar-brand-icon">
<i class="fas fa-school"></i>
</div>
```

Como referencia de lo anterior te dejo este link: 
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Comment: Sí, el problema era que me faltaron referenciar las carpetas donde se encontraban los diseños de los iconos. Ahora tengo otro problema pero será cuestion de seguir investigando o a lo sumo será otro post. Gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa, aun no tengo la reputación para comentar directamente a tu pregunta, así que lo sumo como otra respuesta: Tu duda si es con respecto a los iconos puedes hacerlo aquí, si ya es tema diferente abre post. Saludos.

Comment: Justo ayer estuve comentando las respuestas, me habían faltado las referencias a los diseños de los iconos, por eso no me mostraba nada